# How to pass data from MMC root node to UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, mmc

I'm currently developing an MMC SnapIn in C# that will dynamically populate nodes from a list objects (retrieved in the form of a generic list). This seems to work fine, what I want to do next is pass this object to a UserControl in the Action Pane and populate some fields from object data/fields.

I have the core of the MMC working, however I'm not able to find where the UserControl is actually being instantiated.

The Root node is here, you can see that we foreach over a list - this bit is fine:

```
protected override void OnExpand(AsyncStatus status)
    {
        try
        {
            Children.Clear();
            foreach (var server in new DataAccess().GetAllMonitorServers())
            {
                var x = new ServerNode()
                {
                    DisplayName = "Monitor Configuration - " + server.machineName
                   ,monitorServer = server
                };
                Children.Add(x);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString(), "Monitor Configuration Read Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            ScopeNode node = new ScopeNode(false);
            node.DisplayName = "Error";
            node.ImageIndex = 11;
            node.SelectedImageIndex = 13;
            Children.Add(node);

            return;
        }



    }
```

The Sub Node code is here:

```
    class ServerNode : ScopeNode
{
    private readonly FormViewDescription serverNodeDescription = new FormViewDescription { DisplayName = " test "};
    public MonitorServer monitorServer;
    public ServerNode() : base(true)
    {
        ImageIndex = 18;
        SelectedImageIndex = 18;
        serverNodeDescription.ViewType = typeof(FormView);
        serverNodeDescription.ControlType = typeof(Forms.MonitorConfigurationControl);
        this.ViewDescriptions.Add(serverNodeDescription);
    }

}
```

The code for the UserControl is here:

```
public partial class MonitorConfigurationControl : UserControl
{
    private MonitorServer _monitorServer { get; set; }
    public MonitorConfigurationControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void MonitorConfigurationControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size = this.Parent.Size;

        //MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

What I need is to somehow pass the monitorServer object from the Root Node to the UserControl property _monitorServer so I can do things with it in the view. Documentation on this seems pretty sketchy. Help please.

Comment: _monitorServer is a private property?

Comment: Not anymore, however still I cannot find the root for the instantiation of the UserControl

Comment: The control is instantiated in the InternalInitialize method of the FormView.  The method is internal, so you cant call it. You should be able to get a reference to your control through the Controls property of the FormView though.  I recommend you download [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), and have a look at the code for the FormView/FormViewDescription class in Microsoft.ManagementConsole.dll

Comment: Thanks Sam, will start there.

Comment: You are welcome :)  Good luck